# Wordpress Contact form 7: Passing custom HTML along with form data

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using contact form 7 to create an enquiry form.

On the website, the user can add any number of items to a basket. I have a page with a form to collect personal details, and I'm outputting the basket data on that page also (the basket data is stored using Local Storage).

I want to email the enquiry to the admin, which will include the personal form data, as well as details of each item in the basket.

The only way I can think to do this at the moment is to use a hidden field in the form, add the HTML for the basket items to this field (with JS):

```
// add data to input
var enquiryInput = $('textarea.order-input');
var enquiryInputVal = '';

// loop through each item
$.each(wishlist, function(i, item) {
    $.each(item, function(key, value) {
        if( key === 'ID' ) {
            // do nothing
        } else if( key === 'product' ) {
            // remove hyphens and uppercase each word
            key = key.replace(/-/g, ' ');
            key = key.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){
                return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
            });
            // add to string
            enquiryInputVal += '<b>'+ key +': '+ value +'</b><br/>';
        } else {
            // remove hyphens and uppercase each word
            key = key.replace(/-/g, ' ');
            key = key.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){
                return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
            });
            // add to string
            enquiryInputVal += key +': '+ value +'<br/>';
        }
    });
    enquiryInputVal += '<br/><br/>';
});

// set value of hidden input to show wishlist in enquiry form
enquiryInput.val(enquiryInputVal);
```

...then output it using a traditional CF7 mail tag `[order]`.

The data shows, but it doesn't render the HTML for the field (for obvious security reasons I guess)

Eg (this is what I get in the CF7 HTML email in my inbox):

`<b>Product: Product Title</b><br/>Quantity: 34<br/>Comments: Suspendisse turpis felis, pretium sit amet mollis et, sollicitudin vel eros. <br/><br/><br/><b>Product: Product 2 Title</b><br/>Quantity: 164<br/>Comments: Ut egestas consequat faucibus. <br/><br/><br/>`

Does anyone know a way of passing additional HTML along with form data, and being able to access it in the Mail tab of CF7? I've looked in the docs, but I can't see a hook that seems workable.

Comment: why pass html?  Why not pass basket items ids which I am assuming are some custom post in the back-end?  When a users adds an item to your basket, store the item id in a hidden field and pass that in your submission. You can then [customised your mail body](http://wptips.me/contact-form-7-change-texts-email-body/) according to the item is.

Comment: Ah, that's a much better solution! I actually got it working in the end without using HTML, just a lot of `\r\n`'s and `----`to separate the products. In the future though, I'll be using this method!

Answer (score 2):

**Output Raw HTML in CF7 e-mail body**

Let's say you have `<input type="text" name="my_html" value="">` containing your HTML.

If you put `[my_html]` in your e-mail template, CF7 is using php `htmlspecialchars` ([documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)) to encode the HTML and return it in a safe way. So, what you see in that case, is the actual html code (and not the rendering of that html code).

CF7 provides the filter `wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced` ([documentation](https://contactform7.com/2019/12/08/customizing-mail-tag-replacement/)) to customize a mail-tag replacement in the e-mail body.

You can use that filter to change the output of your `[my_html]` to reverse the encoded html by using the native `htmlspecialchars_decode` ([documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)).

You can write in your function.php :

```
/** 
* Filter to decode the encoded HTML value of the [my_html] tag
* 
* Email-tag value are passed through php htmlspecialchars() to prevent HTML content to break your template.
* Here, we are using htmlspecialchars-decode to output the encoded HTML as raw HTML which will be interpreted as such in the email body.
* @link https://contactform7.com/2019/12/08/customizing-mail-tag-replacement/
* @link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php
*  */

add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced',
  function( $replaced, $submitted, $html, $mail_tag ) {
    // We target the input with the name "my_html"
    // Change 'my_html' with the name of your input
    if ( 'my_html' == $mail_tag->field_name() ) {
        // we decode the encoded value
        $replaced = htmlspecialchars_decode( $submitted );
    }
    return $replaced;
  },
  10, 4
);
```

Now the `[my_html]` output is raw HTML which will be interpreted as such in the email body.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem just now too and solved it by doing what Aurovrata says in the comments. It's slightly different because I'm doing it on the cart page and passing the cart through to the admin email, but it's the same idea. Here's what I did:

- created an event listener on the CF7 form submit button that parses the cart data into a string
- passed the string through a hidden field in the cf7 form
- reconstructed cart data from the string in the wpcf7_before_send_mail hook
- replaced a tag in the email body with my reconstructed cart data
- removed the original hidden field from the email body so that the quantity/product ID string doesn't show up in the email

My email template on CF7 looks like this:

```
[fullname] has requested a shipping quote with the following details:

Email Address: [email]
Address: [address] [city] [postal-code] [state]
Phone: [Phone]

Items in cart are:
[cartcontents]
#CARTCONTENTS#
```

[cartcontents] is a hidden field that I'll use to pass the stringified cart data from the submit button event listener through to the email. Its definition in the CF7 form is this:

```
[hidden cartcontents]
```

I'll replace the #CARTCONTENTS# tag with the reconstructed cart data in the wpcf7_before_send_mail hook and then remove the [cartcontents] field from the email body.

My event listener on the form submit button looks like this:

```
function getCartContents() {
  const cart = document.querySelectorAll("form.woocommerce-cart-form > table.shop_table > tbody tr.woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item.cart_item");

  let cartitems = '';

  cart.forEach( (item) => {
    let qty = item.querySelector('.product-quantity input').value;
    let id = item.querySelector('a').dataset.product_id;
    cartitems += qty+'^'+id+'|';

  });

  cartitems = cartitems.slice(0, -1);    // remove last pipe

  return cartitems;
}

// get submit button
const getShippingQuoteSubmit = document.querySelector('.woocommerce-cart .wpcf7-submit');

if (getShippingQuoteSubmit) {

  getShippingQuoteSubmit.addEventListener('click',function(){

    const cartContents = getCartContents();

    // get the [cartcontents] hidden field & assign cart data
    let cartContentsHidden = document.querySelector(".woocommerce-cart [name='cartcontents']");
    cartContentsHidden.value = cartContents;

  });
}
```

The getCartContents function outputs the cart in a pipe delimited string of quantity^productID - something like 1^543|2^908|1^667

Then, in the wpcf7_before_send_mail hook:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'custom_shipping_quote_wpcf7_email', 10, 3 );
function custom_shipping_quote_wpcf7_email( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {

  $form_id = $contact_form->id();

  if($form_id == 11707) { // need this otherwise it'll break all your other forms
    $posted_data  = $submission->get_posted_data();
    $mail1 = $contact_form->prop( 'mail' ); // get the admin email

    $cartcontents = $posted_data['cartcontents'];
    
    if ( !preg_match('/^[\d|^]+$/', $cartcontents) ) { // make sure $cartcontents only contains nums, | and ^ 
      $mail1['body'] =  str_replace('[cartcontents]','Cart contains invalid data.',$mail1['body']);
      return;
    }

    $cartcontents = explode('|',$cartcontents);

    // reconstruct the cart data into a table
    $cartHtml = '<table><tr><th>Qty</th><th>Product</th></tr>';
    foreach ($cartcontents as $item) {
      $vals = explode('^',$item);
      $product = wc_get_product( $vals[1] );
      $cartHtml .= '<tr><td>' . $vals[0] . '</td><td><a href="' . get_permalink( $product->get_id() ) . '">' .  $product->get_name() . '</a></td></tr>';
    }
    $cartHtml .= '</table>';

    // place cart data into email body 
    $mail1['body'] =  str_replace('#CARTCONTENTS#',$cartHtml,$mail1['body']);

    // remove original [cartcontents] hidden field
    $mail1['body'] =  str_replace('[cartcontents]','',$mail1['body']);

    $contact_form->set_properties( array( 'mail' => $mail1 ) );
  }
}
```

This code explodes the pipe delimited string of cart data, gets the products and assembles it all into a table. Then it replaces the #CARTCONTENTS# tag with that cart data table and removes the original [cartcontents] field from the email body.

This is successfully outputting a table of cart data to the admin email.

The code where I create the table is actually messier than this because you need to put styling in to make the table borders show up, but you can't use classes because Gmail strips them. So you need inline styling and it's messy. You can do something like [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/post-form-submit-hooks-for-tabled-tabbed-mail-tags-remove-word-row/) to make it work, but you could leave it without borders because it is quite readable as is.